# Is it possible to get the saved game progress from PS4 to PC?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I have been playing Assassin's Creed IV: Black Flag on my PS4 a lot. I was just going to play through it once and sell it. Didn't expect it to be this good. I've spent over 30 hours on it. I want to get it on steam (primarily a PC gamer). Because all progress is backed up on the cloud etc, don't have PSN and won't be getting it.

Is it possible to get game progress so far from my PS4 game to the PC game? 
like the save data file? I backed it up from the PS4 to a USB stick, I think the PC game will not recognize it.

I would want to avoid spending another 30 hours to get to the level I am in the game.

Hoping that there is a solution.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning it up, I was not sure if the name of the game should be included in the title or not.

Comment: Forgot to ask about the Uplay fleet missions, do they carry over to the PC version?

Comment: it probably is possible if you hack the hell of the save game but i think the amount of time you'll sink into that would be better spent just playing the game again on PC

Comment: Yeah you are most likely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Progress in Assassin's Creed 4 does not seem to carry over between platforms. While I cannot confirm it for the PS4 `<->` PC transition, I know that it will not carry over between PS3 and PS4. As the files use a different structure and are embedded differently in the game's folders, it would be hard to simply "port" it. Furthermore, it seems that all multiplayer progress as well as Kennway's Fleet is tied to your Uplay account. As this seems to treat different platform versions as different games, these do not carry over.

Some Sources:
[Single player not carrying over to Next-Gen](http://gamerant.com/save-files-next-gen-battlefield-call-of-duty-assassins-creed/); 
[No save game transfer](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/808912-Does-multiplayer-progress-carry-over-from-PS3-to-PS4-Forums); 
[Single player not carrying over to Next-Gen](http://kotaku.com/you-can-upgrade-some-big-fall-games-to-next-gen-but-th-1383775591);
[Multiplayer not carrying over](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/808912-Does-multiplayer-progress-carry-over-from-PS3-to-PS4-Forums)

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, I dont' think there is. For the same reason that you can't play online with consoles from PC. They're written in different code. If you were to do it, save your game onto an external hard drive from the PS4. IF this works, move into your PC program files for AC4. Start game and see if it works.

But like I said, I doubt it would.

Comment: You cannot play online with console players, because Microsoft does not allow it. Sony is a bit more lenient in that regard. Sometimes they allow it. The difference between Console <-> PC Games in terms of code is not that big. 70% of the game is the same code on all platforms, the rest is OS dependent and rendering code. Savegames can work well xplatform, you just need to make sure it is the same loading and saving code, which is most likely the case. -1